# SceneKit autoUpdate

Tags: swiftui, scenekit

Im trying to create app with sceneKit model to show some scene, based on conditions, user choose. at present point everything works fine, scene loads depending on the situation, but it doesn't refresh automatically. basically changes on the scene appears only after reopening the view.
is there any way to refresh scene after some changes made without reopening the view?

this is my code

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit
import CoreData

struct ScullView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(view)
    }

    let view = SCNView()

    @Binding var scene: SCNScene?
    @EnvironmentObject var orderModel: OrderViewModel

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        let view = SCNView()

        let lowJow = scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Mandibola", recursively: true)
        let upJow = scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "up", recursively: true)

        view.allowsCameraControl = false
        
        view.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

        if orderModel.lowJow == true {
            lowJow?.isHidden = false
        } else {
            lowJow?.isHidden =  true
        }
        if orderModel.upJow == true {
            upJow?.isHidden = false
        } else {
            upJow?.isHidden =  true
        }
        

        view.antialiasingMode = .multisampling4X
        view.scene = scene
        view.backgroundColor = .clear

        return view
        
        
    }

    public func renderer(renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        
    }
    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        view.scene?.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
            node.removeFromParentNode()
        }
        
    }
    
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        private let view: SCNView
        init(_ view: SCNView) {
            self.view = view
            super.init()
        }
    }
}

struct FormulaView: View {
    @State var scene: SCNScene? = .init(named: "scull.scn")

    @EnvironmentObject var orderModel: OrderViewModel
    @Environment(\.self) var env
    @Namespace var animation
  
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScullView(scene: $scene)
                .frame(width: 500, height: 500, alignment: .top)
                .padding(.top, -50)
                .padding(.bottom, -15)
                .zIndex(-450)
            Spacer()
                 VStack {

                 Toggle("UJ", isOn: $orderModel.upJow)
                   .padding(.vertical, 10)
                 Toggle("LJ", isOn: $orderModel.lowJow)
                   .padding(.vertical, 10)
          }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Sorry if my question looks stupid. this is my first steps in swift coding

Comment: Can you share information, such about if you can receive some callbacks from the view or scene change. Can you add more clarification?. Btw: when you use SceneKit, you can use also renderer function such as updateAtTime, to i.Ex. check for changes and trigger some function for your update scenario. Another little thing. if you use that app for an iOS device, I do not recoommend you to use special settings like Anti-Aliasing with Multisamping. Better choose none. Also do not enable jittering. Both require a lot of GPU and only works in scenes that do not move.